# CiviMobile: Minimal Permission for CiviMobile

Tags: permissions, civimobile

i am testing out CiviMobile deployment with my CIVICRM (Wordpress 5.0 CIVICRM 5.13) and wanted to see how the app works with a log-in account that has restricted access to selected records in the CIVICRM server.

I have set this account to the CONTRIBUTOR account in WP to differentiate it from the ADMIN account.  And to CONTRIBUTOR role i added the following CIVICRM permissions on top of the default:

1. CiviCRM: view my contact
2. CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API

TESTUSER is the test account used and added to the CONTRIBUTOR role.

I did the access control by only adding TESTUSER to a access control GROUP that is allowed to access a group of records.  TESTUSER was able to access only the intended GROUP of records when loggin into the Wordpress site with just the PERMISSION 2 listed above.

I tried with by logging into CIVIMOBILE, it complained of not sufficent permission so I added PERMISSION 1 and was able to login.

When logged in, i was able to view profile and calendar of the logged in account OK but not able to do so for the accessible records. Their names will appear under CONTACTS but when clicked will complain "PERMISSION REQUIRED"

However, with the same permission set, the SUMMARY page of details for the record is accessible when using the TESTUSER account to log into Wordpress to view the record.

It seems that there might be further permission required to be given to the ACCOUNT that is using CiviMobile to access a restricted set of records.  What would those permissions be?  Thanks.

Comment: I saw somewhere there is a comprehensive Permission list required for CiviMobile here:  https://civimobile.org/permissions/    however, looking at the required permission, it seems that "CiviCRM: view all contacts" is required if the user is to edit/view contacts beyond himself.  If the user needs to be restricted to a group of contacts instead, can this be done in CiviMobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here:

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues/41